# Tables with rounded corners

Tags: itext

I was wondering what would be the best approach for creating tables in a pdf that have rounded corners using the iTextSharp 5.x+ library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have iTextSharp source code, add the following to `PdfContentByte` class:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Enumuration for defining corners you want rounded.
        /// </summary>
        [Flags()]
        public enum Corners {None = 0,All=15,Top=3,Bottom=12, TopLeft = 1, TopRight=2, BottomLeft=4, BottomRight=8};

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a round rectangle to the current path, with rounded conrners as specified by roundCorners.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x"></param>
        /// <param name="y"></param>
        /// <param name="w"></param>
        /// <param name="h"></param>
        /// <param name="r"></param>
        /// <param name="roundCorners"></param>
        public void RoundRectangle(float x, float y, float w, float h, float r,Corners roundCorners)
        {
            if (w < 0)
            {
                x += w;
                w = -w;
            }
            if (h < 0)
            {
                y += h;
                h = -h;
            }
            if (r < 0)
                r = -r;
            float b = 0.4477f;
            if((roundCorners & Corners.BottomLeft) == Corners.BottomLeft)
                MoveTo(x + r, y);
            else
                MoveTo(x, y);

            if ((roundCorners & Corners.BottomRight) == Corners.BottomRight)
            {
                LineTo(x + w - r, y);
                CurveTo(x + w - r * b, y, x + w, y + r * b, x + w, y + r);
            }
            else
                LineTo(x + w, y);

            if ((roundCorners & Corners.TopRight ) == Corners.TopRight)
            {
                LineTo(x + w, y + h - r);
                CurveTo(x + w, y + h - r * b, x + w - r * b, y + h, x + w - r, y + h);
            }
            else
                LineTo(x + w, y + h);

            if ((roundCorners & Corners.TopLeft)  == Corners.TopLeft)
            {
                LineTo(x + r, y + h);
                CurveTo(x + r * b, y + h, x, y + h - r * b, x, y + h - r);
            }
            else
                LineTo(x , y + h);

            if ((roundCorners & Corners.BottomLeft) == Corners.BottomLeft)
            {
                LineTo(x, y + r);
                CurveTo(x, y + r * b, x + r * b, y, x + r, y);
            }else
                LineTo(x, y);
        }
```

Next step is to implment `IPdfPCellEvent` interface:

```
public class myCellEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        #region members
        PdfContentByte.Corners _roundedCorners;
        float _roundness;
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public myCellEvent()
            :this( PdfContentByte.Corners.All,2f)
        {

        }

        public myCellEvent(PdfContentByte.Corners roundedCorners)
            : this(roundedCorners, 2f)
        {

        }

        public myCellEvent(PdfContentByte.Corners roundedCorners,float roundness)
        {
            _roundedCorners = roundedCorners;
            _roundness = roundness;

        } 
        #endregion

        #region IPdfPCellEvent Members
        public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
        {
            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
            cb.RoundRectangle(position.Left, position.Bottom, position.Right - position.Left, position.Top - position.Bottom, this._roundness, this._roundedCorners);
            cb.SetColorStroke(new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black));
            cb.SetColorFill(new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.Beige));            
            cb.FillStroke();
            cb.Stroke();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Then you round what ever corners you want to produce the rounded table of choice:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);


                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(10, atext, f2));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.Padding = 5f;
                cell.CellEvent = new myCellEvent(PdfContentByte.Corners.Top,2f);
                table.AddCell(cell);
```

If you like the answer ... give it a vote :)

Comment: That is great for individual cells but what about the entire table? How could implement TableCell Events to accomplish this.

Comment: Adding another table with one cell that contains my target table works. Thanks again for your answer MK.

Comment: I'am glad that you have found the answer, another approach would be by rounding one corner of each table corner cell (TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft and BottomRight).

Comment: Nice answer MK! Helped me out a lot! :)

Comment: @Inigoesdr It's nice to READ that :)

Answer (score 8):

There's no way to create an iTextSharp `PdfPTable` with rounded corners but what you could do is draw a table border with rounded corners using the `PdfContentByte.RoundRectangle()` method.

Here's a snippet that demonstrates this:

```
Document doc = new Document();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("RoundRectangle Demo.pdf", FileMode.Create)) {
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
    doc.Open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

    // Bottom left coordinates x & y, followed by width, height and radius of corners.
    cb.RoundRectangle(100f, 500f, 200f, 200f, 2f);
    cb.Stroke();

    doc.Close();
}
```

This snippet is a condensed version of code I found in the article [iTextSharp - Drawing shapes and Graphics](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/88/iTextSharp-Drawing-shapes-and-Graphics) on www.mikesdotnetting.com.  You'll want to take a close look at his other articles if you haven't already.

Comment: That worked great. Do you know how I could find the positioning of the table so that I can accurately draw the rounded corners.

Comment: Simplest possible answer

Answer (score 2):

I assume that if you are wanting a table with rounded corners, you're looking for some flashy (or at least pretty) formatting on your table.  If that is the case, I would recommend turning off all the borders in your iTextSharp table, and using a graphic image as the background on your page.  You can then make the graphic background as intricate and fancy as you want (shading, gradients, rounded corners, etc.) with very little trouble.  Then, just line up your table with the background image.

If your data format will change often, you will not want to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Private Function pdfDIF() As Byte()
     Dim celevent As New PdfPCellEvent

```
 Dim tableImportes As New PdfPTable(1)
 tableImportes.SetTotalWidth({10 * dpixcm})

 Dim cellImportes = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("IMPORTE", COURIER9Bold))            
 cellImportes.BorderWidth = 0
 cellImportes.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
 cellImportes.CellEvent = celevent
 tableImportes.AddCell(cellImportes)
```

end function

Public Class PdfPCellEvent
    Implements IPdfPCellEvent

```
Public Sub CellLayout(cell As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell, position As iTextSharp.text.Rectangle, canvases() As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte) Implements iTextSharp.text.pdf.IPdfPCellEve`enter code here`nt.CellLayout
    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = canvases(PdfPTable.LINECANVAS)
   cb.RoundRectangle(position.Left,position.Bottom,position.Width,position.Height,10)
    cb.SetLineWidth(1)
    cb.SetCMYKColorStrokeF(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F)
    cb.Stroke()
End Sub
```

End Class