# iTextSharp - Customize table borders with images

Tags: c#, itext, border

I'm working with iTextSharp, 5.0.2 version, to write a PDF document with the content of a HTML page.

I've got everything working, except I was asked to put round corners on table cells, to create the look of a customized border.

Is it possible? Is it doable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTextSharp 5.0: Tables with rounded corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557217/itextsharp-5-0-tables-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: You are right, I didn't found that question, I'm sorry. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tables with rounded corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557217/tables-with-rounded-corners)